# Read mail from office 365 in java

Tags: java

I have to read mails from office 365 using below code but it's not connecting to the server:

```
private void init()
{
    try{
        Properties smtpProps = new Properties();
        smtpProps.put("mail.host", "192.168.10.18");
        smtpProps.put("mail.port", "995");
        smtpProps.put("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");  

        session = Session.getInstance(smtpProps,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@abc.om","test");
                    }
                  });
            System.out.println("session = "+session);

       Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
       store.connect();
       Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
       inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);           
       Message messages[] = null;
       messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
       System.out.println("leng = "+messages.length);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command in command prompt.
If you get response as "Connecting To 192.168.10.18...Could not open connection to the host, on port 995: Connect failed", issue is with your connectivity with firewall.

```
C:\>telnet 192.168.10.18 995
```

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection refused: connect;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:461)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:258)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:137)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
        at ReadMail.init(ReadMail.java:62)
        at ReadMail.main(ReadMail.java:38)

Comment: execute this command in CMD prompt.  If you get response as "Connecting To 192.168.10.18...Could not open connection to the host, on port 995: Connect failed", issue is with connectivity with firewall.

C:\>telnet 192.168.10.18 995

Comment: it there port name and hostname is different for office 365?

Comment: Actually mail send will use SMTP protocol so it may work for you since that is using port 25. Once ping the telnet using IP and Port lets check that the port number is correct or not

Comment: yes port number will be different based on your server configuration. Can you able to login into mail server using mail admin URL?

Comment: sorry i cant check bcoz its customer machine. if the port no is wrong what it will be? I reffered in google reading mail from office 365 we have to use REST api is it so? pls help me

Comment: It may helpful to you 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes